# Using Automap to map ViewModel to Entity in many-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework-core, automapper

I have two entities and their relationship is many to many. The code is like below:

```
public class Post : Entity
{
    //public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModify { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
public class Tag :Entity
{
    //public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}
public class PostTag :Entity
{
    //public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
public class PostViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModify { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public List<TagViewModel> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I had created the mapping configure from entity to viewmodel:

```
CreateMap<Post, PostViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Tags, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PostTags))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Author.User.LastName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Body, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Body))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Title))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CreateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CreateTime))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LastModify, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastModify))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Tags, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PostTags.Select(y => y.Tag).ToList()));
```

My question is, when I receive a PostViewModel like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] PostViewModel postViewModel)
{

}
```

how can I map the PostViewModel to Post? And I want to create an Entity from the PostViewModel and add them, which is post, tag(if not exist) and postTag relationship, into DbContext, what should I do?

I am pretty new to automapper and this is my first question, I hope I am doing right thing and I really appreciate your answer and guid for how to ask.

Comment: Check Automapper.Collection.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Could you kindly give an example?

Comment: No, but many people do this, so it should be easy to find.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thank you anyway, I have figured it out.

Answer (score -1):

You have two choices I think.

1) [Reverse mapping](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html)

You can just add `.ReverseMap()` to the end of your mapping config

```
CreateMap<Post, PostViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Id))
    ...
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Tags, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PostTags.Select(y => y.Tag).ToList()))
    .ReverseMap();
```

2) You can define a new configuration for `PostViewModel` to `Post`

```
CreateMap<PostViewModel, Post>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Author.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AuthorId))
    ...etc
```

Then `Mapper.Map<Post>(postViewModel)`

Comment: Can I have a comment for the down vote please? That way I can firstly amend my answer, secondly so that everyone can learn.